# Are there any synonyms for phrases such as 'in fact', 'in practice', and 'practically speaking'?

Tags: writing, tech-writing

In the context of formal article writing, sometimes, I have to use the phrases such as 'In fact', 'in practice', or 'practically speaking', are there any synonyms for these phrases to improve my writing?

Comment: We can answer questions about word request s where there is a specific situation with an example sentence given. However, as should be evident from the [Tour], general questions about improving one’s writing style are off-topic here.